# Jquery: exclude element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('a[rel]').each(function()
   {
      $(this).qtip(
      {
         content: {
            text: '<img class="middle" src="i/icon_processing.gif" alt="l">Loading...',
            ajax: {
               url: $(this).attr('rel')
            },
            title: {
               text: $(this).text(),
               button: true
            }
         }
    })
      .click(function() { return false; });
   });
});
```

This code make all rel's on pages to work with tipsy jquery plugin. 
The problem is that i have a specific div with some id, that holds content with rel that needs to be excluded from this function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `not()` to exclude elements:

```
$('a[rel]').not('#IdOfElement').each(function()
```

Comment: That would only eliminate A tags with the id of "IdOfElement", and not A tags INSIDE a DIV with that id.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:not()` in your selector.

For example: `$("a[rel]:not(div#divId a[rel])")`

A jsfiddle illustrating the use of the `:not` selector in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/6s6Mm/

Comment: +1 Interesting, didn't know you could use `:not` in a selector

Comment: does it affect performance?  Seems like more text parsing this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude specific Elements with the .not() function like this:

```
$('a[rel]').not('#sepcialElement').each(...);
```

Comment: That would only eliminate A tags with the id of "IdOfElement", and not A tags INSIDE a DIV with that id.